# how to get image from a source to view on my blackberry simulator

Tags: blackberry

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bundling images with Blackberry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368605/bundling-images-with-blackberry)

hi i am doing blackberry application development for OS 5.0 using eclipse IDE but i cant find the code for getting a PNG image file from a source to be viewed on my blackberry simulator.

Comment: There are already posts similar to your query, see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2368605/bundling-images-with-blackberry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paste an image on ***`res`*** folder on your project.

[image].

Then use `Bitmap.getBitmapResource(..)` to get the image.

```
Bitmap myImage = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("my_image.png");
```